# How to show Datediff hh:ss format?

Tags: sql

Running the queries below i get the output '16:6' and '3:40'.
It shows the zero on the second one, but for the first it shows '16:6'

The first one makes it look like '16:60' which by time would be wrong.

How can I make it show '16:06' and not mess up anything else?

```
SELECT
    right('0' + convert(float,datediff (second, '2015-02-09 10:58:42.202','2015-02-09 11:14:48.245')/ 60 ), 2) + ':' +
right('0' + convert(float,datediff (second, '2015-02-09 10:58:42.202','2015-02-09 11:14:48.245')% 60),2)  as total_time

SELECT
    right('0' + convert(float,datediff (second, '2015-02-09 08:07:35.284','2015-02-09 08:11:15.863')/ 60 ), 2) + ':' +
right('0' + convert(float,datediff (second, '2015-02-09 08:07:35.284','2015-02-09 08:11:15.863')% 60),2)  as total_time
```

Comment: Which DBMS? SQLServer, Oracle, SQLite, MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR()` instead of `FLOAT`:

```
SELECT
    right('0' + convert(VARCHAR(4),datediff (second, '2015-02-09 10:58:42.202','2015-02-09 11:14:48.245')/ 60 ), 2) + ':' 
   +right('0' + convert(VARCHAR(4),datediff (second, '2015-02-09 10:58:42.202','2015-02-09 11:14:48.245')% 60),2)  as total_time
```

The point of the `RIGHT('0'+ ... ),2)` portion is to add a leading zero to 1-digit values, but it only works on strings.

If you want to show more than 2 digits for the minutes portion you'll have to change how you go about adding leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is T-SQL, with one `datediff`:

```
SELECT
right(convert(varchar, dateadd(second, datediff(second, '2015-02-09 10:58:42.202','2015-02-09 11:14:48.245'), 0), 108), 5) as total_time
```